# Is it possible to use aggregate functions on an ActiveRecord Virtual Attribute of a Model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two Models similar to these (please don't mind the context, I'm just trying to illustrate an example and a client-purchase relation was the first thing that came to mind):

```
# client.rb
# name:string

class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :purchases, dependent: :destroy

   def profit
     self.purchases.sum('price - cost')
   end
end

# purchase.rb
# client_id:integer, product_id:integer, cost:decimal, price:decimal

class Purchase < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :client
  belongs_to :product
end
```

This works for single records, like this:

```
> a=Client.first # OK
> a.profit       # 40.23
```

However, if I want to make a SUM of the value of "profit" (which is a SUM on itself), I get an error, which is perfectly understandable.

```
> a.sum(:profit)   # no such column: profit
```

Is there a way to get a SUM out of these without running a loop through the entire table? Currently I do something like this:

```
sum=0
Client.each do |a|
   sum+=a.profit
end
```

This works, however I'm wondering if there's an easier way to do this via ActiveRecord, or perhaps even in SQL?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use your :profit method directly, but you can get the calculated value for each Client without iterating through each.  Use `group` and `sum` together:

```
Purchase.group(:client_id).sum('price - cost')
```

This will return a Hash where the keys are the `client_id` and the value is the sum of all purchases `price - cost` for that client.

Comment: I have an small issue. Say the `price` field was in the `Client` Model instead of Purchase (ignore the context for a minute). How would you make this calculation?

Comment: That would be something like `Client.includes(:purchases).group('clients.id).sum('clients.price - purchases.cost')`

Comment: Alright, that'd give me the result from each `Client`. Is there a way to make a sum of everything? Sorry if I sound like I'm going in circles, the specific query I want to do is kinda complex to explain.

Comment: Just remove `.group('clients.id')` and you'll get one summary value for all clients.

Comment: Thanks, that is working. One final caveat. In the first query you mentioned with the `group` method, I'm getting results with 0 as the SUM. I'm assuming this is cause the `LEFT OUTER JOIN` is returning `NIL` values for the Clients without Purchases. Is there a way for these to turn into 0, so they can be calculated? For instance, if I use `sum('clients.price - 2')` I get whatever value `Price` has, minus 2. But if I leave it with `purchases.cost`, I get 0s, or the actual calculation when they do have a value in `purchases.cost`.